# Unclosed <a> or <div> tag somewhere on page causing unwanted hyperlink

Tags: html

This is my page: http://mysampletestsite345.com

The white box is populated by a mySQL table using a basic PHP loop. For some reason, the last link in the box is attaching itself to the Twitter feed on the right side as well as the Copyight 2011 text, which I do not want. I can't tell where the missing tag goes. Anyone willing to donate a pair of eyes to my problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Test the URL at [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsalarydump.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&ss=1) and you'll get a response quickly:

> Warning Line 113, Column 314: unclosed
>   start-tag requires SHORTTAG YES
>
> …uld end up as one of the biggest
>   draft or waiver wire steals of the
>   year.'</a>
>
> The construct <foo<bar> is valid in
>   HTML (it is an example of the rather
>   obscure “Shorttags” feature) but its
>   use is not recommended. In most cases,
>   this is a typo that you will want to
>   fix. If you really want to use
>   shorttags, be aware that they are not
>   well implemented by browsers.

Looking at the markup, I found that the image tag on line 113 was not closed:

```
<a href = 'http://smysampletestsite345.com/dir/page1'>
  <img
   width = '500px'
   style = 'vertical-align: middle;'
   src = '/images/sample.jpg'
   title = '<h2>Best [..] of the year.'</a>
```

You should put a `>` before the closing `</a>`. This error occurs in the lines following 113 as well.

Comment: Oh wow, I had completely forgotten about W3 Validator... your suggestion of closing the <img> tag fixed it. Thanks!